# Azure Logs, cant find it

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I can't find the logs on azure.

[See here](https://ibb.co/h11ywvM)

Can you help me ?

ps locally deploying works (got authentification set to individual)

Comment: First blade: Just below overview --> Audit Logs or Second blade: Under "Monitoring" section --> App Service Logs. Which one you're after?

Comment: @GauravMantri first of all, thank you for answering. I was using the template from microsoft(asp.net core 3, setting authentification method to individual). Applying migration(locally + to azure db), as soon as I deploy to azure I get that error. Don't know whats wrong, cant find the error log   ...